# How can I use unescaped characters with Embedded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm following the documentation here

https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Suppose I have

```
var text = "Birds & Bees";

<%= text %>
```

Prints the string escaped as documented.  I have tried

```
<%- text %>
```

Which also prints the string as escaped.  Is there anything else I can try to get this to work?